# How to make XMLUnit to ignore the order of text elements and return customized comparison result?

Tags: compare, diff

I'm comparing 2 xmls using "org.xmlunit.diff" in Java and it returns the differences with the following code.

```
public class XMLComparator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Path to the XML files
    File file1 = new File("output_old.xml");
    File file2 = new File("output.xml");

    // Perform XML comparison
    try {
        Diff diff = DiffBuilder
                .compare(Input.fromFile(file1))
                .withTest(Input.fromFile(file2))
                .ignoreWhitespace()
                .checkForSimilar()
                .build();  
        
        if (diff.hasDifferences()) {
            System.out.println("Differences found:");

            for (Difference difference : diff.getDifferences()) {
                System.out.println(difference.toString());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No differences found.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output_old.xml  has this

```
<projectArea>
    <fullName>SMALLCELL</fullName>
    <id>_6MrXgEx7Ee6GUol3yT5KIw</id>
    <members>
        <AD_ID>xxxxxx</AD_ID>
        <DNG_ID>aaaaaa</DNG_ID>
        <roles>
            <name>Author</name>
        </roles>
    </members>
    <members>
        <AD_ID>yyyyyy</AD_ID>
        <DNG_ID>bbbbb</DNG_ID>
        <roles>
            <name>Author</name>
        </roles>
    </members>
```

And, output.xml looks like this

```
<projectArea>
    <fullName>SMALLCELL</fullName>
    <id>_6MrXgEx7Ee6GUol3yT5KIw</id>
    <members>
        <AD_ID>xxxxxx</AD_ID>
        <DNG_ID>aaaaaa</DNG_ID>
        <roles>
            <name>default</name>
        </roles>
    </members>
    <members>
        <AD_ID>yyyyyy</AD_ID>
        <DNG_ID>bbbbb</DNG_ID>
        <roles>
            <name>Administrator</name>
        </roles>
        <roles>
            <name>Author</name>
        </roles>
        <roles>
            <name>default</name>
        </roles>
    </members>
```

I get the comparison differences like this

```
Expected text value 'Author' but was 'default' - comparing <name ...>Author</name> at /projectAreasWrapper[1]/projectArea[16]/members[1]/roles[2]/name[1]/text()[1] to <name ...>default</name> at /projectAreasWrapper[1]/projectArea[16]/members[1]/roles[2]/name[1]/text()[1] (DIFFERENT)
Expected child nodelist length '3' but was '5' - comparing <members...> at /projectAreasWrapper[1]/projectArea[16]/members[2] to <members...> at /projectAreasWrapper[1]/projectArea[16]/members[2] (DIFFERENT)
Expected text value 'Author' but was 'Administrator' - comparing <name ...>Author</name> at /projectAreasWrapper[1]/projectArea[16]/members[2]/roles[1]/name[1]/text()[1] to <name ...>Administrator</name> at /projectAreasWrapper[1]/projectArea[16]/members[2]/roles[1]/name[1]/text()[1] (DIFFERENT)
Expected child 'null' but was 'roles' - comparing <NULL> to <roles...> at /projectAreasWrapper[1]/projectArea[16]/members[2]/roles[2] (DIFFERENT)
Expected child 'null' but was 'roles' - comparing <NULL> to <roles...> at /projectAreasWrapper[1]/projectArea[16]/members[2]/roles[3] (DIFFERENT)
```

For the second member, even though Author role exists in both xmls it shows in the comparision difference as it doesn't seem to ignore the order.

1. Is there way for XMLUtil to ignore the order of text elements while comparing?
2. Is it possible customize response messages in diff output? It seems bulky. I need process in response in the application to do some action based on the difference..

Appreciate help with the above questions.

Comment: I tried ElementSelectors.byNameAndText but it doesn't work

Diff diff = DiffBuilder
                    .compare(Input.fromFile(file1))
                    .withTest(Input.fromFile(file2))
                    .ignoreWhitespace()
                    .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byNameAndText))
                    .checkForSimilar()
                    .build();